# php doesn't process the sources

Tags: php, apache

I'm build and install php 5.5.8 and apache web server. As said in php docs I'm added the following config:

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

to `httpd.conf`. I'm restart the server, but there is no effect. PHP code displayed just as text. I'm check that `/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so` is exist. 
I'm configured php as follow

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --enable-sockets --enable-simplexml --enable-xmlreader --enable-xslt
```

now I'm just execute the following bash commands:

```
make
make install
```

It were executed correctly. Further I'm add the configs to httpd.conf as I'm specified above. 
What is the possible reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a product like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), your php installation is not configured correctly. The all-in-one apps tend to save a lot of headache

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to understand how to configure php installation. Where I can read about?

Comment: http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/

Comment: I assume you're running on windows... if not, just google installing apache and php on XXXXX and you should be able to find a mountain of info. Getting a server securely configured can be a task, good luck.